# how to making the navigation menu size equal to the navigation menu child size?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation menu. Inside the navigation menu I have child navigation menu. I want the size of navigation menu equal to the child navigation menu.

I created three hyper-tags and then there is a div element which is the element after the hyper tags. I am floating the three hyper tags as well as div element to the left.
the div element contains one button and div. I am setting the child div element to be absolute so its drawing itself below the button. I want the size of button to be equal to the size of the div element which contains child links. I thought if I set the root div element with position relative it will have the same width of the button but its not working. Here the css and html code. Any answers would be really appreciated.

```
/* css */

<style>
        .navbar {
            background: #006669;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .navbar a{
            float: left;
            padding: 15px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.1rem;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .navbar .subnav{
            float: left;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .navbar .subnav .subnavbutton{
            padding: 15px 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.1rem;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            background: transparent;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        .navbar .subnav .subnavcontent{
            position:absolute;
            border: 1px solid red;
            min-width: 100px;
            display: none;
        }
        .navbar .subnav .subnavcontent a{
            float: none;
            color: #444;
            background: white;
            display: block;

        }
        .navbar .subnav .subnavcontent a:hover{
            background: #a0a0a0;
        }
        .navbar .subnav:hover .subnavcontent{
            display: block;
        }

    </style>

     here is the body content

<div class="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">News</a>
        <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbutton">Contact</button>
            <div class="subnavcontent">
                <a href="#">link1</a>
                <a href="#">link2</a>
                <a href="#">link3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Bootstrap` framework and hence use their pre-programmed dropdown menu?

Comment: I am learning html and css first once I have a good understanding of css and html I will move towards bootstrap. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full width dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292490/full-width-dropdown-menu)

Comment: In the full width dropdown menu the width of the child navigation menu is 100%. I want the width should be same as the width of stay connected. simply I want the width of the parent navigation menu to be same of the size of child nav

Comment: can you help me by suggesting something in my code which I wrote.

Comment: Hello. Why are you using CSS overflow: hidden on the root div? That's a side question. My potential solution to your answer is set the size of the nav divs using either percentages or maybe preferably with pixels. Let me know what you think?

Comment: I am setting the root div with a css overflow:hidden because that clears float . The other thing I could do was clear fix to the root div. both solution will clear float. The wrapper container will have the required width and height. Thank you for asking AlexDev

Answer (score 0):

I can do what you want using a flex-box based nav

html

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="dropdown-menu">Menu</a>
      <ul id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
nav ul {
  background: #006669;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #006669;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  border: 1px solid #006669;
}
```

Comment: upon closer inspection is it not just the subNavContent width setting is off. change from "min-width: 100px" to "width: 90px" and that seems to line up better.

Comment: thank you I will work as you mentioned and see if it work. thanks Niall Flannery